# Shopping Cart Rules for New Sign Up/Registered Customers

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

How can I create a new shopping cart for **new registered customers**?

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

I want to give **15% discount** to my new customers for them to use only once.

How can I set up with this?